# Iptables 443 woes? Need help editing a rule

Tags: linux, shell, networking, iptables

I am trying to edit the iptables rule below or at least to increase the limit to 20 or more. How to achieve that?

```
48       0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:443flags: FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN #conn src/32 > 10 reject-with tcp-reset
```

Reason being is that my son is getting constant disconnection from his game BUT will work if I tether my phone to his computer and route the 443 connections to it. Basically having the same internet as the default route for his pc and all 443 connections from his game to my phone's data connection. I was wondering if that iptable rule is causing the issue. Thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this rule on his computer or on a machine that act as a router. And you are trying to limit the TCP connections to 20?

Comment: on a router running on and old linux shell. I'm trying to increase the limit to see whether that is affecting the 443 drop outs. Thank you.